# How do I solve inverse of 3x3 matrices without using a library?

Tags: javascript, math, matrix, inversion

```
 <html>
<head>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.2.1/math.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="result">loading result...</p>
  <script> 
   var inverted = math.inv([[1,2,4],[3,4,5],[7,8,9]]);
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = JSON.stringify(inverted);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I have using math.js but I'm curious as to how i can do this without using a library.

Comment: How would you do it with pen and paper?

Comment: the best way to get help here on stack is to put the code you have tried to solve your problem (right now, you are simply asking for a straight up, full code solution) and tell where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure matrix is "full" as in: no missing values.
The following code works on matrices with row count!=column count as well.

```js
var originalMatrix=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
function invertMatrix(matrix) {
  return matrix.reduce(
    (acc, cv)=> {
      cv.reduce(
        (acc2, cv2, idx2)=> {
          if(acc[idx2]==undefined) acc[idx2]=[];
          acc[idx2].push(cv2);
        },[]
      );
      return acc;
    },[]
  );
};

console.log(originalMatrix);
console.log(invertMatrix(originalMatrix));
console.log(invertMatrix(invertMatrix(originalMatrix)));

var anotherMatrix=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15]];

console.log(anotherMatrix);
console.log(invertMatrix(anotherMatrix));
console.log(invertMatrix(invertMatrix(anotherMatrix)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Your code appears to compute the transpose of a matrix. That is not, in general, the inverse

Comment: @dmuir, you are correct.
I've mis-read/mis-comprehended the question.
When I studied Matrices, It wasn't in English = this causes (too many) misunderstandings...
I still have to stop and think which is a point and which is a line when encountering "Vertex" and "Edge", for example...
I'll work on code for "Inverse" soon.
Thanks again!

Comment: if this is not an answer to the question, the fact that it was accepted will mislead a lot of visitors looking for code that lets them invert a 3x3 matrix. It would be a good idea to either update this post to actually show code that inverts the matrix, or delete the post so that it can't mislead visitors anymore.

Answer (score 1):

from https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/168828/find-the-inverse-of-a-3-by-3-matrix/168837#168837

This is a variant of the js code that provides a 3x3 2d array rather than a single 9x1 array.

```js
function inverse(m) {
  [
    [a, b, c],
    [d, e, f],
    [g, h, i]
  ] = m;
  let x = e * i - h * f,
    y = f * g - d * i,
    z = d * h - g * e,
    det = a * x + b * y + c * z;
  return det != 0 ? [
    [x, c * h - b * i, b * f - c * e],
    [y, a * i - c * g, d * c - a * f],
    [z, g * b - a * h, a * e - d * b]
  ].map(r => r.map(v => v /= det)) : null;
}

function writeout(arr) {
  return JSON.stringify(arr, function(key, val) {
    return val.toFixed ? Number(val.toFixed(4)) : val;
  });
}

const mA = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 3],
  [3, 1, 2]
];
const invA = inverse(mA);
const inv_invA = inverse(invA);


document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<p>mA:</br>" + writeout(mA) + "</p>" +
  "<p>invA:</br>" + writeout(invA) + "</p>" +
  "<p>inv_invA:</br>" + writeout(inv_invA) + "</p>";
```

```html
<p id="result">loading result...</p>
```